# Lucene.net - Search for terms within a phrase

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I created an index like so:

```
var doc = new Document();
doc.Add(new Field("id", product.Id.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
doc.Add(new Field("name", product.Label, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
writer.AddDocument(doc);
```

What I am trying to accomplish is search for exact match of any terms within the phrase. Let say, my index contains 2 documents ('test 123', 'foo')

If I enter a phrase like:

- 'I am foo' it then returns the doc 'foo'
- 'I am a test' should return nothing
- 'I am test 123' returns 'test 123'

Searching for a single element like 'foo' within a phrase that don't contain any whitespace is working fine. 
But I am stuggling when the phrase contains a white space. 'I am test 123' returns nothing as well as 'test 123'.

I suspect it might come from the anylizer, so I tried StandardAnalyzer as well as KeywordAnalyzer, but the issue remains. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using entity it gives something like that : Context.Entity.Where(x => phrase.ToLower().Contains(x.Term.ToLower())).ToList();. How can I do the same request with an index in Lucene instead of targetting the database every time ?

Answer (score 0):

When i search with strings i do:

var searchString = "I am foo";
var searchTerms = searchString.Split(' ');

And the query would be looking something like:

```
+(name:i name:am name:foo) name:"I am foo"
```

to explain: 
+ before the query means, that one of the terms needs to be there before it is a match.
i individually search each term, more matches = higger score
i search on the searchString as a prase also, because then i make sure that if it is a direct match it will get the highest score.

You can even make searches with fuzzy and Wildcard, so you reach very wide, but still get the best results at the top.

Hope it helps.